# PHP imagepng() is creating corrupt image

Tags: php, image, png

I have searched everywhere to find a possible solution to my problem. Unfortunately I cannot seem to figure it out. I have a .php file that creates an image based on other images. I had the script working exactly as it is right now before without flaws. But after fiddling around with some other files it suddenly stopped working and is generating corrupt .png images now on Firefox, Chrome and IE.

**image.php**

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_reporting", 2047);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
error_reporting("E_ALL");

include("GameEngine/Database.php");
if(isset($_GET['uid'])){
    $uid =  $_GET['uid'];
} else {
    $uid = "1";
}
if(isset($_GET['size'])){
    if($_GET['size']=='profile'){
        $size =  '31x40';
    }elseif($_GET['size']=='inventory'){
        $size =  '64x82';
    }elseif($_GET['size']=='sideinfo'){
        $size =  '119x136';
    }
} else {
    $size = "119x136";
}
$herodetail = $database->HeroFace($uid);
if($herodetail['color']==0){
    $color = "black";
}
if($herodetail['color']==1){
    $color = "brown";
}
if($herodetail['color']==2){
    $color = "darkbrown";
}
if($herodetail['color']==3){
    $color = "yellow";
}
if($herodetail['color']==4){
    $color = "red";
}
$geteye = $herodetail['eye'];
$geteyebrow = $herodetail['eyebrow'];
$getnose = $herodetail['nose'];
$getear = $herodetail['ear'];
$getmouth = $herodetail['mouth'];
$getbeard = $herodetail['beard'];
$gethair = $herodetail['hair'];
$getface = $herodetail['face'];

// USAGE EXAMPLE: 
$body = imagecreatefrompng('img/hero/head/'.$size.'/face0.png');
if($getbeard!=5){
    $beard = imagecreatefrompng('img/hero/head/'.$size.'/beard/beard'.$getbeard.'-'.$color.'.png');
}
$ear = imagecreatefrompng('img/hero/head/'.$size.'/ear/ear'.$getear.'.png');
$eye = imagecreatefrompng('img/hero/head/'.$size.'/eye/eye'.$geteye.'.png');
$eyebrow = imagecreatefrompng('img/hero/head/'.$size.'/eyebrow/eyebrow'.$geteyebrow.'-'.$color.'.png');
if($gethair!=5){
    $hair = imagecreatefrompng('img/hero/head/'.$size.'/hair/hair'.$gethair.'-'.$color.'.png');
}
$mouth = imagecreatefrompng('img/hero/head/'.$size.'/mouth/mouth'.$getmouth.'.png');
$nose = imagecreatefrompng('img/hero/head/'.$size.'/nose/nose'.$getnose.'.png');
$face = imagecreatefrompng('img/hero/head/'.$size.'/face/face'.$getface.'.png');

// SAME COMMANDS: 
$database->imagecopymerge_alpha($body, $face, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($face), imagesy($face),100); 
$database->imagecopymerge_alpha($body, $ear, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($ear), imagesy($ear),100);
$database->imagecopymerge_alpha($body, $eye, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($eye), imagesy($eye),100);
$database->imagecopymerge_alpha($body, $eyebrow, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($eyebrow), imagesy($eyebrow),100);
if($gethair!=5){
$database->imagecopymerge_alpha($body, $hair, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($hair), imagesy($hair),100);
}
$database->imagecopymerge_alpha($body, $mouth, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($mouth), imagesy($mouth),100);
$database->imagecopymerge_alpha($body, $nose, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($nose), imagesy($nose),100);
if($getbeard!=5){
$database->imagecopymerge_alpha($body, $beard, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($beard), imagesy($beard),100);
}

// OUTPUT IMAGE: 
header("Content-Type: image/png"); 
imagesavealpha($body, true); 
imagepng($body, NULL);
?>
```

I have tried commenting out the header() so that I can check if there is an error in any of the PHP before the image gets rendered. This is not the case. I have tried all $variables in an  tag to check if these rendered properly. They did. I am at a loss as to what the problem could be.

My only guess right now is that there is a whitespace or carriage return which somehow gets added to the final render causing it to corrupt. However, I have searched for this possible whitespace for ages and cannot seem find it.

Any tips and/or suggestions are extremely appreciated!

**SOLVED
One of the files this script was including was saved as UTF-8 with BOM. This gave the image an extra byte making it corrupt. Saving all the files as UTF-8 without BOM fixed my problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see the problem (unless there are some error reporting going on?), but if you save the image from the brower to a file and then open it in a text-editor, the problem may be obvious.

Edit: It turned out to be the byte-order-mark in an utf-8 file.

Comment: Saving the image and loading it in a .txt editor will yield me a whole bunch of strange ASCII characters which a normal image file should load. However the first line is:

�PNG

Should that ASCII character be in front of the PNG?

Comment: No. I guess it is the byte order mark of a utf-8 file. Save your file as another encoding or utf-8 without BOM. I've also gotten quite a few grey hairs from BOMs turning up until I understood what was going on.

Comment: The image.php file was already saved as UTF-8 without BOM. The image file is only created as a header Content-Type: image/png. In any case: I just saved the image.php file as Cp1252, still got the same result (a corrupt image).

Comment: Checking a known good png, I have to admit, I was wrong. There are two bytes before the "PNG" ...

Comment: I just found out that one of the .php files that gets included changed to UTF-8 with BOM. However, trying to change this to Cp1252 in Zend did not seem to have removed the BOM? (It still gives me the following message: Byte order mark is UTF-8 (BOM)). Any idea on how to change this?

Comment: MortenSickel, I have fixed the error. The included file was saved as a UTF-8 (BOM). Creating a new file and pasting the code in there and saving it as UTF-8 without BOM fixed my error! Everything works again! Thank you!

Comment: I often came across this when I was working in windows, then I used notepad++ that had functionality for selecting how to save the file. Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

just happend to search, and found : https://github.com/yi12345/TravianT4/blob/master/hero_image.php which is 100% the same...  sure you didn't mess up something in the Database.php?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however it seemed to be an issue with db_MYSQL.php being saved as UTF-8 with BOM.

Comment: close enough tho ;).   I see you got good company here. Good Luck